# Pypal IPN VERIFIED but Paypal keep retrying

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am testing IPN In sandbox. At my website I log this communication between Paypal and my site

```
Start validations:_notify-validate,16.94,Eligible,confirmed,SVWAAUVZX2S4Y,0.00,1 Main    St,13:57:50 May 07, 2012 PDT,Completed,windows-1252,95131,Test,0.84,US,Test   User,3.4,,verified,demarc_1336421374_biz@gmail.com,United States,San  Jose,1,As4zhnwQeMSnsOdh0NBxc2GkfRrEAd8OPZnnd3EWRDz38L81PzX-6vI- ,demarc_1321350258_per@gmail.com,6FT25620DT6366410,instant,User,CA,demarc_1336421374_biz@gmail .com,,6SHJZ2PT5YMLS,web_accept,test item,EUR,,US,1,0.00,test item,,0.00,de0561482901
2012-05-07 22:52:47 Paypal: ResponseVERIFIED
2012-05-07 22:52:47 Paypal: 1
2012-05-07 22:52:47 Paypal: Processing Trasaction: 4fa8361f-7574-444f-b821-5e660a00000f
2012-05-07 22:52:47 Paypal: 4fa8361f-7574-444f-b821-5e660a00000f
```

It seems ok, uh? But if I login into Sandbox with the business account, in IPN History I see that Paypal is keeping trying to send IPN. At my website, where I log transaction into database, I see a lot of records (which I store if the response is verified).
How is it possible?
I do a post back to Paypal with cakephp
    function isValid($data ){

```
$data['cmd'] = '_notify-validate';
$newData['cmd'] = '_notify-validate';
foreach ($data AS $key => $val) {
$newData[$key] = $val;
}
    $this->log("Start validations:".join(",",$newData), 'paypal');
    $data = array_map(array('PaypalIpnSource', 'clearSlash'), $newData);

    if (isset($data['test_ipn'])) {
        $server = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    } else {
        $server = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }

    $response = $this->Http->post($server, $newData);
      $this->log("Response".$response, 'paypal');

    if ($response == "VERIFIED") {
        return true;
    }

    if (!$response) {
        $this->log('HTTP Error in PaypalIpnSource::isValid while posting back to PayPal', 'paypal');
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

I do not think it is a problem of cakephp or whatever.
I set in the sandbox business account EUR as currency. And also the currency value in the paypal submission form is in EUR.
Any help appreciated after days of googling.

Comment: Try to send IPN to your URL through IPN tool and see what would be the status. May be somehow 200 is not sent to PP. It IPN tool will say IPN Sent OK, then we have to look in the other place.

Answer (score 0):

Your IPN endpoint must reply with HTTP status code 200 to the PayPal's notification. Otherwise the status will stay "Retrying".